# Is there a way to iterate through a list and change a string based on the list contents?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm brand new to python and trying to learn by doing and have started my first real project. Not even 4 hours in and I've hit a huge snag. I'm trying to pair down possible input variants so that I can use that input to reference a dictionary. No idea if this is even possible and haven't been able to figure it out using references. If possible, am I even remotely close?

```
yeast_check = ['lalvin', 'zymaflore', 'actiflore', 'redstar', ' ', 'fermemtis', 'lallemand', 'safale', 'bourgoblanc', 'bourgorouge', 'k1','icv', '-']

yeast_input = input('enter yeast type:')

def yeast_convert(yeast_input):
    for check in list(yeast_check):
        yeast_input = yeast_input.replace(check, '')
        return yeast_input
```

Comment: did you call the function?

Comment: As you are given code I can't see you call `yeast_convert` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yeast_check = ['lalvin', 'zymaflore', 'actiflore', 'redstar', ' ', 'fermemtis', 'lallemand', 'safale', 'bourgoblanc', 'bourgorouge', 'k1','icv', '-']

yeast_input = input('enter yeast type:')

def yeast_convert(yeast_input):
    for check in list(yeast_check):
        yeast_input = yeast_input.replace(check, '')
    return yeast_input

print(yeast_convert(yeast_input))
```

Try calling it after the for loop

Comment: Well I feel dumb. Thanks!